# how to secure my desktop app with a uniq machine id

Tags: .net, api, security, ca, license-key

How to secure my desktop app to only work on specific machines which i accept through API requests, for example hardCoded MacAddress List Allowed but it can be changed so do u have any other solution ?

- CA using IP won't Working.
- and even CA with MacAddress can't work as Mac can be changed with moving Client CA to Hacking Machine.
- mix of systeminfo include maCAddress, host name and so on can all be changed as well
  any suggesstions ?